# React-native ,AxiosError: Network Error on Android but works fine on IOS

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, axios

I'm facing `AxiosError: Network Error` issue on Android  but works fine in iOS.
error-- [AxiosError: Network Error]

`"axios": "^1.3.4",`

`"react-native": "0.68.2",`

But on Postman it's working.

[image]

```
const URL ="https://helpdesk.plymouthplace.us"


axios.get(URL + "/api/v1/helpdesk/url",{params:{ 'url': URL}})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log('response--', response.data)
  }).catch((error) => {
  console.log('error--', error)
  });
```

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the issue which is SSL certificate problem in the api request
(* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

- Closing connection 12)
  but in iOS there is no problem like SSL certificate problem and api call response is successful.

Anyone have some idea about it.